# How to check if userInputted string characters are contained in selected string?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

- Reports whether or not every character in source occurs at least once in         target.
- Examples: containsAll("abc", "abracadabra") is true, and containsAll("def", "Defect") is false.
- IMPLEMENTATION NOTE: Write this as an accumulation loop. Don't try to write a doubly-nested loop!

So I have to use an accumulation loop to basically see if the userInputted string characters appear in the selected string.

Below I have my code and below that is what I'm using as its test case.

```
 public static boolean containsAll (String source, String target)
{
    boolean contains = false;
    scn = new Scanner (source); 


             String token = scn.next();


             if(target.contains(token) || token.isEmpty()) {
                 contains = true;
             }



        return contains;
}
```

This is the test case. The first one does not work, but the rest work fine.

```
@Test
public void testContainsAll ()
{
    assertTrue(containsAll("", ""));
    assertTrue(containsAll("abc", "abracadabra"));
    assertFalse(containsAll("def", "Defect"));
    assertFalse(containsAll("x", ""));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Reports whether or not every character in source occurs at least once in target" is not what `contains` method does since it checks if string contains specified substring, not if it contains all characters from that substring regardless of their order or amount. You need to iterate over string characters and check if some character in other string is equal to it.

Comment: ``scn.next()`` gives you the next word, not the next character...

Comment: Ok one sec lol. Im trying to figure to do it rn.

Comment: Wait so how do I change that? @f1sh

Comment: What did you find when you looked for `java iterate over characters in string` in your favorite search engine?

Comment: String s = "...stuff...";

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    char c = s.charAt(i);        
    //Process char
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to all that helped. My code creates a Boolean variable and initializes it to true. Then I create a for loop which iterates through all the characters of the userInputted string and if target does not contain the value of that character at that iteration then contains is set to false. otherwise I return contains which was previously initialized to true.

```
public static boolean containsAll (String source, String target)
{

    boolean contains = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++)
    {

        if (!target.contains(String.valueOf(source.charAt(i))))
        {
            contains = false;
        }
    }

    return contains;

}
```